# Ethernet works on Ubuntu, not on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, windows-8.1, ethernet

I have pretty strange problem. I have dual boot of windows 8.1 & ubuntu. The thing is that ethernet perfectly works on Ubuntu, but won't work on Windows 8.1. All it says in Win is that is Udentified Network and with No Internet Access. I don't know what to do, if you need some much info from my Win8.1, just give me to know

Comment: Try do disable the fast startup feature of Windows 8 and restart Windows.

Comment: Its already done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below steps and check your outcome. Hope this should help you.

1. Right click on the Network adapter and try 'Disable' and 'Enable'
2. Right click on the Network adapter and try Disconnect and Connect
3. Go to Start > Computer > right click > Manage > on the right pane, select the Network adapter > right click and choose 'Uninstall'. Once the Uninstall finished, click on Search for New hardware changes. This will install the wireless adapter again
4. Right click on the Network adapter > Properties > select "Internet Protocol version 4(TCP/IP) > Properties > click on "Obtain IP address Automatically" > click on OK.

Comment: Has anyone had any success/issues with this fix? I'm going to attempt this as soon as I get home.